# TypeError: Object has no method 'command' in selenium

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-rc

I'm writing a [Selenium soda](https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda) test.
When I use method aliases to avoid args copyPasting...

```
var method = bool ? browser.clickAndWait : browser.click; 
method("css=button:first", function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

... I get a `TypeError`:

```
/pathToMyProject/node_modules/soda/lib/soda/client.js:478
      return this.command(cmd, args, fn);
              ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'command'
```

Full code:

```
var soda = require('soda'),
    assert = require('assert');


var browser = soda.createClient({
    host: 'localhost', port: 4444, url: 'http://google.com', browser: 'firefox'
});

browser.session(function (err) {
    browser.open('/', function (err, body, res) {
        if (!err) {
            bool = false;
            var method = bool ? browser.clickAndWait : browser.click;
            method("css=button:first", function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

If I only use `clickAndWait` or `click`, everything works fine, however, I want to choose which method depending on the value of `bool`.

The arguments of both functions are the same, so why doesn't this work? When I use simple functions without `soda`, like below, things work fine:

```
var a = function(){};
var b = function(){};
var c = bool ? a : c;
c();
```

I get the same error using `apply`:

```
var args = ["css=button:first", function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}];
browser.click.apply(undefined, args);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your example works is that there are no dependencies between `a`, `b`, and `c`; they are all simple functions. It is not always possible to to just make a reference to a method of an object. In your case, `soda` likely calls `command` from within the `method` reference you create, except that the scope is wrong.

If the function works with either (but not when making a reference to the function), why not just do something like this:

```
//...
var myFunction = function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

if (bool) {
    browser.clickAndWait("css=button:first", myFunction);
} else {
    browser.click("css=button:first", myFunction);
}
// ...
```

Or a shorter variation:

```
// ...
(bool ? browser.clickAndWait : browser.click)("css=button:first", myFunction);
// ...
```

Alternatively, you may just need to set the scope when you call apply:

```
// ...
var method = bool ? browser.clickAndWait : browser.click;
method.apply(browser, ["css=button:first", function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}]);
// ...
```